# Delete checkbox that has an 'inactive' status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table shown below:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" /></th>
         <th colspan="2">Status</th>
         <th class="data-name">UserName</th>
         <th class="data-name">Description</th>
   </thead>
</table>
```

The Status uses a text to indicate active and inactive users. Here I'm trying to display an error msg if anyone tries to delete the checkbox that has status as 'active'. Only 'inactive' users can be deleted.
I'm looking for a jquery code for that. can someone help me?
I'm providing a sudo code of what i'm trying to achieve. this might not be syntactically correct.

```
if $('#selectall input[type="checkbox"]:checked') is 'active'
{  
    alert('do not delete the checkbox');
}
else
{
    alert('delete the checkbox');
}
```

Comment: And where is this `active` and `inactive` text ?

Comment: You mean... **disabled?**

Comment: Why not just disable the checkbox altogether if the row is 'active,' preventing it from being checked in the first place? That'd provide more clear direction to the user.

Answer (score 0):

this might do it

```
if ($('#selectall input[type="checkbox"]:checked').size() > 0)
{  
    alert('do not delete the checkbox');
}
else
{
    alert('delete the checkbox');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i developed his next code in javascript and html

http://jsfiddle.net/jHpKB/1/

I hope you help

(My english is bad sorry)

html

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" /></th>
         <th colspan="2">Status</th>
         <th class="data-name">UserName</th>
         <th class="data-name">Description</th>
      </tr>

   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" data-user-id="1" data-status="active" /></td>
          <td>Active</td>
          <td>User 1</td>
          <td>None</td>          
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-user-id="1" data-status="inactive" /></td>
          <td>Inactive</td>
          <td>User 1</td>
          <td>None</td>          
       </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectall").on("click", function(){
        var checked =  $(this).is(":checked");

        $("input[type='checkbox'][data-status='inactive']").attr("checked", checked )

    });
});
```